# grep unknown flag - (?!5)

Tags: regex, grep

I got this from the bash logs of another user.
I have no idea with the (?!5) on the grep is.
I am not really sure what the GREP_COLOR is, but thos most mytifying is the (?!5)

also in ht e second grep the user uses a (?: - which mystifies me as well.

```
casper@casperfoo:/local/data/log $ GREP_COLOR='01;32' grep -P --color '\]: (?!5:).*\* . YELP'
/local/data/log/ulpx-0210.34804.log
STATS 10/1 07:58:59.541179 34804 menhir_service.cpp:301 [handleMarketDataSubs]: 10: market 3 mnemonic - *: * . YELP
STATS 10/1 08:00:06.192371 34804 menhir_service.cpp:301 [handleMarketDataSubs]: 60: market 3 mnemonic - *: * . YELP
STATS 10/1 08:25:11.278688 34804 menhir_service.cpp:301 [handleMarketDataSubs]: 527: market 3 mnemonic - *: * . YELP
STATS 10/1 08:25:12.332410 34804 menhir_service.cpp:301 [handleMarketDataSubs]: 543: market 3 mnemonic - *: * . YELP
STATS 10/1 08:25:14.731410 34804 menhir_service.cpp:301 [handleMarketDataSubs]: 552: market 3 mnemonic - *: * . YELP
STATS 10/1 08:25:14.973049 34804 menhir_service.cpp:301 [handleMarketDataSubs]: 556: market 3 mnemonic - *: * . YELP
STATS 10/1 08:25:14.983558 34804 menhir_service.cpp:301 [handleMarketDataSubs]: 560: market 3 mnemonic - *: * . YELP

casper@casperfoo:/local/data/log $
casper@casperfoo:/local/data/log $
casper@casperfoo:/local/data/log $ GREP_COLOR='01;32' grep -P --color '\]: (?:10|60|527|543|552|556|560):.*app.name'  /local/data/log/ulpx-0210.34804.log
DEBUG 10/1 07:58:59.472317 34804 menhir_service.hpp:140 [on_open]: 10:  app.name -> prod/ulpx.celoxica.2
DEBUG 10/1 07:58:59.502264 34804 menhir_service.cpp:78 [handleProperties]: 10: app.name=prod/ulsub10
DEBUG 10/1 08:00:05.129861 34804 menhir_service.hpp:140 [on_open]: 60:  app.name -> prod/ulpx.celoxica.2
DEBUG 10/1 08:00:05.154347 34804 menhir_service.cpp:78 [handleProperties]: 60: app.name=prod/ogen-10b-3
DEBUG 10/1 08:25:11.193841 34804 menhir_service.hpp:140 [on_open]: 527:         app.name -> prod/ulpx.celoxica.2
DEBUG 10/1 08:25:11.263360 34804 menhir_service.cpp:78 [handleProperties]: 527: app.name=prod/qgen-amxo-3
DEBUG 10/1 08:25:12.254483 34804 menhir_service.hpp:140 [on_open]: 543:         app.name -> prod/ulpx.celoxica.2
DEBUG 10/1 08:25:12.316808 34804 menhir_service.cpp:78 [handleProperties]: 543: app.name=prod/qgen-xisx-3
DEBUG 10/1 08:25:14.589141 34804 menhir_service.hpp:140 [on_open]: 552:         app.name -> prod/ulpx.celoxica.2
DEBUG 10/1 08:25:14.715101 34804 menhir_service.cpp:78 [handleProperties]: 552: app.name=prod/qgen-xcbo-2
DEBUG 10/1 08:25:14.796188 34804 menhir_service.hpp:140 [on_open]: 556:         app.name -> prod/ulpx.celoxica.2
DEBUG 10/1 08:25:14.842203 34804 menhir_service.hpp:140 [on_open]: 560:         app.name -> prod/ulpx.celoxica.2
DEBUG 10/1 08:25:14.953661 34804 menhir_service.cpp:78 [handleProperties]: 556: app.name=prod/qgen-xpho-2
DEBUG 10/1 08:25:14.964403 34804 menhir_service.cpp:78 [handleProperties]: 560: app.name=prod/qgen-xbox-2
casper@casperfoo:/local/data/log $
```

Comment: the `-P` option for grep instructs grep to use Perl-compatible regular expressions. See http://www.pcre.org/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html .

Specifically the `Grouping and Capturing` section:

> Place parentheses around multiple tokens to group them together. You can then apply a quantifier to the group. E.g. Set(Value)? matches Set or SetValue.
>
> Parentheses create a capturing group. The above example has one group. After the match, group number one contains nothing if Set was matched. It contains Value if SetValue was matched. How to access the group's contents depends on the software or programming language you're using. Group zero always contains the entire regex match.
>
> Use the special syntax Set(?:Value)? to group tokens without creating a capturing group. This is more efficient if you don't plan to use the group's contents. Do not confuse the question mark in the non-capturing group syntax with the quantifier.

And the `Lookaround` section:

Lookaround is a special kind of group. The tokens inside the group are matched normally, but then the regex engine makes the group give up its match and keeps only the result. Lookaround matches a position, just like anchors. It does not expand the regex match.

> q(?=u) matches the q in question, but not in Iraq. This is positive lookahead. The u is not part of the overall regex match. The lookahead matches at each position in the string before a u.
>
> q(?!u) matches q in Iraq but not in question. This is negative lookahead. The tokens inside the lookahead are attempted, their match is discarded, and the result is inverted.
>
> To look backwards, use lookbehind. (?<=a)b matches the b in abc. This is positive lookbehind. (?
>
> You can use a full-fledged regular expression inside the lookahead. Most applications only allow fixed-length expressions in lookbehind.

See [`man grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for `GREP_COLOR`.

> --color[=WHEN], --colour[=WHEN]
>
> Surround the matched (non-empty) strings, matching lines, context lines, file names, line numbers, byte offsets, and separators (for fields and groups of context lines) with escape sequences to display them in color on the terminal. The colors are defined by the environment variable GREP_COLORS. The deprecated environment variable GREP_COLOR is still supported, but its setting does not have priority. WHEN is never, always, or auto.